# Not getting response when sending post request to node server

Tags: node.js, express

I am using Express with node js. If I run my HTML template on different host or server (other than the one which my application is running) then I am not getting any response.

If I make post request to the node server from a file hosted on same server then it gives a JSON response successfully.

I want to create a REST API application, so everyone can just post a request and use response data.

My code of the HTML file (running on locally on the node server):

```
<script type="javascript">
function submitit() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var id = $('#pw').val();
    var obj = {
        name: name,
        id: id
    };
    //posting on node server
    $.post('http://localhost:3001/user', {
        data1: obj
    }, function (data, status) {
        alert(data);
        //window.location.href = "http://google.com";
    }, 'json')
}
</script>
<body>
    <h1 class="hone">Log in to site.</h1>
    <form method = "post" id="yourform">
        user id :<input type="text" id='name' name="userid" /><br />
        password :<input type="text" id='pw'  name="password" /><br />
    </form>
    <input id="formsubmit" type="button" onclick='submitit();' value="login" /><br />
    <div id="flash"></div>
</body>
```

app.js on the node server:

```
app.post("/user", function (req, res) {
    console.log("ok");
    //var h=req.params.name;
    var user = {
        "name": "sdf",
        "add": "f"
    };
    //var r = req.body.name;

    console.log(user);
    console.log(req.body.data1);
    res.json(user);
});
```

This is working fine if I request from the same host, but if send a request from a file a different machine it's not working.

Comment: You are changing the url (`http://localhost:3001/user`) to reflect the change of server, right? Also, perhaps your other server is blocking incoming traffic? Your app is not explicitly listening on `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: My Both server are running on different port..! i want to make cross communication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got solution, have to just add middle ware for cross domain communication

add bellow middle ware to yout app.js or script code.

```
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    next();
}

app.use(allowCrossDomain);
```